# Two threads start a task but at any point thread B never goes ahead of thread A

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Two threads A and B together start printing numbers from 1 - 100 and only constraint is that thread B can never go ahead of thread A at any point and both the threads should work like usual apart from this constraint.

So I did see some answers here on stack Overflow which used join() on thread A before starting thread B but I believe that means Thread B will not start until thread A has finished execution but that means the end of Multithreading.

One solution which I tried requires creating two runnable objects having same implementation that prints numbers 1 - 100 and then start two threads on each objects.
But in run method for Thread B before printing the numbers I used Thread.sleep(10);

This way Thread B never go ahead of Thread A i.e. Whatever number B prints A has already printed it on the console.
Do you guys think that this retains multithreading and also follows the constraint?

Is there any other way of doing this?
Is it possible to achieve the same with one runnable object between two threads?

Comment: Think of something that involves `wait`/`notify` on some shared monitor object, rather than relying on `Thread.sleep()`

Comment: Okay not familiar with the wait / notify yet and how they work but I will look into this direction thanks.

Comment: Better to avoid wait/notify, it was not designed for this kind of thing and introduces complications. Using semaphore is a much better idea.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). You initialize it with a given number of permits, and only that number of permits can be used at any given point; anyone who needs more has to wait for one to be released.

So, initialize it with 0 permits. Start counting on both threads: after A counts each number, have it release a permit. Before B counts, have it acquire one.

At the very beginning, B can't acquire any permits (there are 0 available), so it blocks trying to acquire one. When A counts to 1 and releases a permit, B can acquire the one and count to 1. And so on.

> Is it possible to achieve the same with one runnable object between two threads?

The Semaphor approach would require two Runnables. I'm not sure how you could formalize the "A ≥ B" requirements without that or sleep/timing (which doesn't actually formally establish the invariant, it just makes it extremely extremely likely), since at minimum you need a way to tell each thread whether it's the leader or follower. You could do it with a ThreadLocal to establish the thread's "mode", but that's effectively two Runnables in just a more complicated way.

Comment: Okay, after reading your comment I can see how this is possible using semaphore, I will study its usage and implementation and try to apply thanks.

Comment: I would even initialize it with 0 permits and have thread A release one permit every time it counts a number. (According to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#%3Cinit%3E(int) this is a valid usage - you are allowed to even start with a negative number of permits).

Comment: @ThomasKläger D'oh! Yes, that's a much simpler way to do it. :) I updated my answer — thanks for the suggestion!